# Beautifulsoup select an element based on second last child

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to select second last child from the breadcrumbs section.

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <span><a href="/">Home</a></span>
    <i class="arrow"></i>
    <span><a href="/list1/">List Name 1</a></span>
    <i class="arrow"></i>
    <span><a href="/list2/">List Name 2</a></span>
    <i class="arrow"></i>
    <span>List Name 3</span>
</div>
```

I write code in BS4 python to print second last child data to show (**List Name 2**)

```py
r = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')  
    
listname = soup.select_one('.breadcrumbs span:nth-last-child(2) a').text
    
print(listname)
```

But it gives error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Sometime page has 2 breadcrumbs and sometime has 3. That is why I only need second last name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to select all `<a>` inside breadcrumbs and use `[-1]` index:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_code = """\
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <span><a href="/">Home</a></span>
    <i class="arrow"></i>
    <span><a href="/list1/">List Name 1</a></span>
    <i class="arrow"></i>
    <span><a href="/list2/">List Name 2</a></span>
    <i class="arrow"></i>
    <span>List Name 3</span>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, "html.parser")

print(soup.select(".breadcrumbs a")[-1].text)
```

Prints:

```
List Name 2
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that the reason why `:nth-last-child(2)` did not work is that the `span` element you wanted was not the second to last, but the third to last child. In order to get the second to last `span` you have to restrict the `:nth-last-child` check to only `spans`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

TEXT = """
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <span><a href="/">Home</a></span>
    <i class="arrow"></i>
    <span><a href="/list1/">List Name 1</a></span>
    <i class="arrow"></i>
    <span><a href="/list2/">List Name 2</a></span>
    <i class="arrow"></i>
    <span>List Name 3</span>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(TEXT, "html.parser")
listname = soup.select_one('.breadcrumbs > :nth-last-child(2 of span) a').text
print(listname)
```

Prints

```
List Name 2
```